# Seekbar doesnt play from the point where it is dragged by the user

Tags: android, seekbar

I have the problem with the seekbar thumb, although I have added every necessary codes for it to work. still the seekbar thumb doesn't play from the point dragged by the user. instead the thumb positioned itself back to the point it was last playing though. Any help will be appreciated.

```
    plus = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    minus = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);


    player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.songnames);


    player.setLooping(false);
    im = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);


    seekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.mantraProgressBar);
    seekbar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
    seekbar.setProgress(0);
    seekbar.setMax(player.getDuration());
    new Thread(this).start();


    im.setOnClickListener(this);
    player.start();
    im.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause_tran);

    Toast.makeText(this, isPlaying, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    plus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int cu = player.getCurrentPosition();
            player.seekTo(cu - 5000);
        }
    });
    minus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int cu = player.getCurrentPosition();
            player.seekTo(cu + 5000);
        }
    });


}


@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    if (arg0.getId() == R.id.imageButton3) {
        if (player.isPlaying()) {
            player.pause();

            Toast.makeText(this, notPlaying, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            ImageButton img1 = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);

            img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_tran);

        } else {
            player.start();
            Toast.makeText(this, isPlaying, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            ImageButton img1 = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
            img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause_tran);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {
    int currentPosition = 0;
    String s;
    int total = player.getDuration();
    while (player != null && currentPosition < total) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            currentPosition = player.getCurrentPosition();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return;
        }

        seekbar.setProgress(currentPosition);


    }


}
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    if (fromUser) {
        player.seekTo(progress);
        seekbar.setProgress(progress);
    }
}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

}
}
```

Comment: Probable Reason: You are setting max progress to seek bar using "seekbar.setMax(player.getDuration());" and when plus/minus image clicks then you are setting new seek position using "player.seekTo(cu + 5000);/player.seekTo(cu - 5000);". You should add or subtract position in propertion to the max progress you set before.

Comment: I doesn't seems to be problem associated with that buttons. although I tried to make it work removing that buttons. still the seekbar probem persist. Please. Please. help. I want it to work asap. so that I could submit it in time.

Comment: @Sam try this one   player.seekTo(progress* 1000); in onProgressChanged

Comment: @Nisarg I tried it. but still it does the same.

Comment: @Sam did you try what Sagar Trehan was trying to convey !!

Comment: @Nisarg yeah. above that I also tried to remove that buttons for sake of it might work.

Answer (score 0):

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private MyVideoView mVV;
private Handler mhandler;
private SeekBar seekbar;
private int duration;
private int backPositon = 0;
private int currentPosition;
private SharedPreferences sp;
private MediaController controller;
private TextView tv_curr;
private TextView tv_duration;
private Handler handler;
private boolean mExit;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mVV = (MyVideoView) findViewById(R.id.vv);
    seekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
    tv_curr = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_currtime);
    tv_duration = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_duration);

    //get duration of video
    getDuration();
    //video start
    playVideo();
    //get current time
    getCurrentDuration();
    //listener
    initEvent();

}

private void initHanlder() {
    handler=new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            if (msg.what==0x123){
                tv_curr.setText(timeFormat(mVV.getCurrentPosition()));
                seekbar.setProgress(mVV.getCurrentPosition());
            }

            if(msg.what==0x133){
                int changedProgress = msg.arg1;
                tv_curr.setText(timeFormat(changedProgress));
                mVV.seekTo(changedProgress);
                seekbar.setProgress(changedProgress);
                mVV.start();
            }
        }
    };

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (mVV.getCurrentPosition()<duration){
                Message message = Message.obtain();
                message.what=0x123;
                handler.sendMessage(message);
                SystemClock.sleep(1000);

                if(mExit){
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
    }).start();

}


private void getDuration() {
    mVV.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            duration = mVV.getDuration();
            timeFormat(duration);
            Log.d("TAG", "---duration" + timeFormat(duration));
            seekbar.setMax(duration);
            //TextView  time
            tv_duration.setText(timeFormat(duration));
            //init handler
            initHanlder();
        }
    });
}

private String timeFormat(int time) {   
    StringBuilder mFormatBuilder;
    Formatter mFormatter;
    mFormatBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    mFormatter = new Formatter(mFormatBuilder, Locale.getDefault());
    int totalSeconds = time / 1000;

    int seconds = totalSeconds % 60;
    int minutes = (totalSeconds / 60) % 60;
    int hours = totalSeconds / 3600;

    mFormatBuilder.setLength(0);
    if (hours > 0) {
        return mFormatter.format("%d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds).toString();
    } else {
        return mFormatter.format("%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds).toString();
    }

}

private void playVideo() {
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "cgx_video/db.mp4");
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdir();
    }
    Log.d("TAG", file.toString());
    mVV.setVideoPath(file.getPath());
    mVV.start();

}


private void initEvent() {
    seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
           currentPosition=progress;


        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
             mVV.pause();


        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            if(handler!=null){
                Message message = Message.obtain();
                message.what=0x133;
                message.arg1=currentPosition;
                handler.sendMessage(message);
            }


        }
    });


}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.d("TAG", "---onPause");
    mVV.pause();
    backPositon = mVV.getCurrentPosition();
    Log.d("TAG", "backPositon:" + backPositon);

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.d("TAG", "---onStop");

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d("TAG", backPositon + "---backPositon");
    mVV.seekTo(backPositon);
    mVV.start();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    //in case of leak of memeroy
    mExit=true;
    super.onDestroy();

}
```

}

Comment: it didn't work either. what else can I do so as to make it work.

Comment: still seeking for relevant answer.